# hilt: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] Repository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt, clean-architecture, multi-module

I am creating a multi module android app with clean architecture layers as modules:

```
root >
       app (main module)
       presentation (android lib module) //it has dependency on domain in build.gradle
       domain (android lib module)
       data (android lib module) //it has dependency on domain in build.gradle
```

**Domain** module has UseCase and Repository interface like:

```
package com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.usecase.user


class SaveUserUseCase @Inject constructor(
     private val repository: UserCredentialsRepository,
     @IO private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {

     ...
}
```

---

```
package com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.respository

interface UserCredentialsRepository {

...

}
```

and the implementation of Repository & its di is placed in **Data** module with data sources like:

```
package com.cleanarchitecturesample.data.repoimpl

import com.cleanarchitecturesample.data.source.local.UserCredentialsLDS
import com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.respository.UserCredentialsRepository

class UserCredentialsRepositoryImpl(
     private val userCredentialsLDS: UserCredentialsLDS
) : UserCredentialsRepository {

    ...
}
```

---

```
package com.cleanarchitecturesample.data.di

import com.cleanarchitecturesample.data.repoimpl.UserCredentialsRepositoryImpl
import com.cleanarchitecturesample.data.source.local.UserCredentialsLDS
import com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.respository.UserCredentialsRepository
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideUserCredentialsRepository(
        userCredentialsLDS: UserCredentialsLDS
    ): UserCredentialsRepository = UserCredentialsRepositoryImpl(userCredentialsLDS)

}
```

Everything seems to be fine but still I am getting following error:

/AndroidStudioProjects/CleanArchitectureSample/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debug/com/cleanarchitecturesample/app/CleanArchitectureApp_HiltComponents.java:137: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.respository.UserCredentialsRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements CleanArchitectureApp_GeneratedInjector,
^
com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.respository.UserCredentialsRepository is injected at
com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.usecase.user.IsValidUserCredentialsUseCase(repository, …)
com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.usecase.user.IsValidUserCredentialsUseCase is injected at
com.cleanarchitecturesample.presentation.vm.UserAuthenticationVM(…, isValidUserCredentialsUseCase, …)
com.cleanarchitecturesample.presentation.vm.UserAuthenticationVM is injected at
com.cleanarchitecturesample.presentation.vm.UserAuthenticationVM_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.cleanarchitecturesample.app.CleanArchitectureApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.cleanarchitecturesample.app.CleanArchitectureApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.cleanarchitecturesample.app.CleanArchitectureApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
It is also requested at:
com.cleanarchitecturesample.domain.usecase.user.SaveUserUseCase(repository, …)

*

> `Note: I have also tried di for Repository using the abstract class and binds syntax with even that was showing the same error.`

- 

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in Advance!! :)

Comment: As you haven't added code of ```UserCredentialsLDS``` , i assume you have added ```@Inject``` on constructor of ```UserCredentialsLDS```

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani, for that also the di in both ways I have tried the @ Provide and @ Binds. But doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `data` module as a dependency of `app` module.

Dagger generated codes stay in `app` module as such if you don't set `data` module as a dependency dagger won't be able to access your `RepositoryModule`

Comment: Hi @TheOneT,

I was stuck in this issue since 3 days... your solution resolved the issue. Thank you so very much Bro!!! :)

It made my day.

Comment: @mithil1501if the above answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I also faced this problem and this answer finally solved it!
@mithil1501 Please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Hi @lonut and Thomas Cirksena, I forgot to mark the answer as correct, which I did now.